# How can i implement a code so the snake won't go opposite direction

Tags: python, pygame

Hello i have been struggling, to make is so that the snake head can't move to the left if it is moving to the right same for up and down. I understand i need to make some direction for the snake so i can compare ot to each other i just don't know how to implement this.
code:

```
# Snake game.
import pygame

import random

pygame.init()

# Kleur voor slang / food.
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (50, 153, 213)
green = (0, 255, 0)

# Start screen.
win_width = 800
win_height = 600
window_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake game by Smerfy')

snake_block = 10
snake_speed = 20

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font_style = pygame.font.SysFont("bahnschrift", 25)
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 35)


def your_score(score):
    value = score_font.render(f"Your Score: {score}", True, red)
    window_screen.blit(value, [0, 0])


def snake(snake_blk, snake_list):
    for x in snake_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(window_screen, red, [x[0], x[1], snake_blk, snake_blk])


def message(msg, color):
    msg = font_style.render(msg, True, color)
    msg_rect = msg.get_rect(center=(win_width / 2, win_height / 2))
    window_screen.blit(msg, msg_rect)


def game_loop():
    game_over = False
    game_close = False

    # Start punt snake hoofd x,y.
    x1 = win_width / 2
    y1 = win_height / 2

    x1_change = 0
    y1_change = 0

    snake_list = []
    lenght_of_snake = 1

    foodx = round(random.randrange(0, win_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
    foody = round(random.randrange(0, win_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0

    while not game_over:

        while game_close:
            window_screen.fill(blue)
            message("You Lost! Press C-Play Again or Q-Quit", red)
            your_score(lenght_of_snake - 1)
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    game_over = True
                    game_close = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    game_loop()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x1_change = -snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x1_change = snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y1_change = -snake_block
                    x1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y1_change = snake_block
                    x1_change = 0
        if x1 >= win_width or x1 < 0 or y1 >= win_height or y1 < 0:
            game_close = True

        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change

        window_screen.fill('black')
        pygame.draw.rect(window_screen, green, [foodx, foody, snake_block, snake_block])
        snake_head = [x1, y1]
        snake_list.append(snake_head)
        if len(snake_list) > lenght_of_snake:
            del snake_list[0]

        for x in snake_list[:-1]:
            if x == snake_head:
                game_close = True

        snake(snake_block, snake_list)
        your_score(lenght_of_snake - 1)

        pygame.display.update()

        if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0, win_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(0, win_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            lenght_of_snake += 1
        # Snelheid van de slang.
        clock.tick(snake_speed)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()


game_loop()
```

I have no idea how to implement something so it can compare to each other likethe following:
if direction != 'down'
direction = 'up'

```
if self.direction == 'left':
    self.x[0] -= size
if self.direction == 'right':
    self.x[0] += size
if self.direction == 'up':
    self.y[0] -= size
if self.direction == 'down':
    self.y[0] += size
self.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to define a direction variable at the start of `game_loop`:

```
direction = 'right'
```

You'll then need to edit the input section of the code to something like this:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and direction != 'right':
            x1_change = -snake_block
            y1_change = 0
            direction = 'left'
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and direction != 'left':
            x1_change = snake_block
            y1_change = 0
            direction = 'right'
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and direction != 'down':
            y1_change = -snake_block
            x1_change = 0
            direction = 'up'
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and direction != 'up':
            y1_change = snake_block
            x1_change = 0
            direction = 'down'
```

Comment: Thank you it really helped me to understand how to make sure none 2 keys are inputed at same time /D